# How to implement Vue.js applications with Spring MVC or other server-sided frameworks?

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, vue.js, vuejs2, frontend

I've already read the official Vue.js documentation about building app. What I understood is, by using vue-cli, *.vue files are built (or compiled ?) into a javascript file which is injected in index.html file.

What if I don't have any index.html ? In my current application, html documents are built at runtime from jsp template files, how can I have Vue inject js and 'asset' built files into a chosen jsp template ?

Plus, node server should be used in development mod, is this mandatory ?

Comment: I think what you talking about is Vue [Single File Component](https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/single-file-components.html) which is not mandatory to be used, and need webpack (or browerify). You can use Vue directly by importing it in a <script> tag in your JSP

Answer (score 0):

I would copy the generated javascript file and put it in the public/static folder. Then on the jsps that would use it, just add a script tag that would point to it and the empty div#app.

Comment: Is there any away to configure vue-cli to append generated stuff to a desired file ?

Comment: Not that I'm aware of.

Comment: Well, I will give a try to a symlink (it sounds like cheat though)